# Postgres pgAdmin Docker Compose: Unable to connect to server connection to server, timeout expired

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin

I'm running a [simple Docker Compose script](https://gist.github.com/acenelio/5e40b27cfc40151e36beec1e27c4ff71) to instantiate Postgres and pgAdmin for local development.

It works fine on Windows via Power Shell as administrator, but in Linux I'm getting this error:

*Unable to connect to server connection to server at '172.18.0.3' port 5432 failed: timeout expired*

[image]

How to solve it?